# Minimal Distinct Lengths in Complete Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, plane-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

Normally, complete graph $K_n$ is drawn as a regular $n$-gon with all diagonals, or a $n-1$-gon with an added point at the center. Occasionally a grid will be used.

Most of the time, the $n$-gon seems to minimize the number of distinct edge lengths. But not always. For example, $K_{12}$ and $K_{19}$ need 6 and 9 distinct lengths in either polygonal form. The below grid-based embeddings need only 5 and 8 distinct lengths.

[image: graphs with few distinct lengths]

Are there other solutions that surpass both grid and polygon-based methods?

Comment: Come to think of it, your solutions are also a grid, just a _trigonal_ one. I expect it to be asymptotically better than the rectangular grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the solution of [Erdős distinct distances problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_distinct_distances_problem), minimal number of distinct edge lengths in a planar (straigh line) drawing of $K_n$ is $\Theta(n/\log n)$. The Wikipeadia page contains many relavant links, so I add only two links to MathOverflow questions:

[Point sets in Euclidean space with a small number of distinct distances](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80223/point-sets-in-euclidean-space-with-a-small-number-of-distinct-distances)

[Erdős distance problem n=12](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58203/erdos-distance-problem-n-12_)